# Generate the lexicographically first permutation(recursive backtracking)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

The input is a number `n`, a number `m`, and an array of size `3*n`, whose elements are either 0s or numbers from 1 to `n`, where `1<=n,m<=30`. I need to make an algorithm to generate the lexicographically first permutation of the set{1,...,n}, where every element appears exactly 3 times, where two equal numbers have a minimum of`m` different numbers between them. Only the 0s are to be replaced, while any number that isn't 0 has to stay the same.

For example, for `n=5`, `m=1` and the array `1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5` the output should be `1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 3 5 3 4 5 4 5`.

I came up with this code. It doesn't output the lexicographically first permutation. It outputs
`1 2 3 4 5 1 3 2 3 4 5 1 2 4 5`

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int counters[100]={3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3};

bool verify_permutation(int V[], int n, int m){
    array<int,100> POZ;
    POZ.fill(m);;
    for(int i = 1;i<=3*n;i++){
        if(V[i]==0)
            return false;
        for(int j = 1;j<=3*n;j++){
            if(POZ[V[j]]<m)
                return false;
            POZ[V[j]]=0;
            for(int k = 1;k<=n;k++){
                POZ[k]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int j = 1;

void backtracking(int V[], int x, int m, int n){
    if(verify_permutation(V,n,m)){
        for(int i = 1;i<=3*n;i++)
            cout<<V[i]<<' ';
        return;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=3*n;i++){
        if(counters[j]==0)
            continue;
        if(V[i]!=0){
            counters[V[i]]--;
            continue;
        }
        j++;
        if(j>n)
            j=1;
       
        if(V[i]==0){
            counters[j]--;
            V[i]=j;
            backtracking(V,j,m,n);
            counters[j]++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    int V[31];
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    if(m>=n){
        cout<<-1;
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3*n; i++){
        cin >> V[i];
    }
    backtracking(V, 1, m, n);
}
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Is your algorithm incorrect or does your code not follow your algorithm?

Comment: `x` is unused... It should probably be used to get rid of global `j`. Mutable global variable are tricky to use in recursive functions.

Comment: *"where two equal numbers have `m` different numbers between them"*, unclear what means this contraints. `4 3 5 3 4` there are 3 (2 distinct) numbers between the two `4`... it is neither difference between consecutive numbers as `3 5` has difference of 2...

Comment: @Jarod42 i edited the question, it should have said a minimum of m different numbers

Comment: Are you sure about expected output? `.. 3 4 5 3 5 4 5` < `.. 3 5 3 4 5 4 5`  (your expected)